# Program works in CLion IDE, but exe doesn't work

Tags: c++, clion

I started programming in C++ using CLion IDE.
When I run the program inside the IDE it works. However, opening the `.exe` file outside the IDE generates a bunch of errors:

```
The code execution cannot proceed because libgcc_s_seh-1.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem.
```

Hitting OK pops the same message again with a different dll.
Why does this happen? What are the different ways to fix it? What is the best option?

Comment: The computer cannot find the DLL that implements the Standard Library. Either supply the DLL with the executable or read up on "static Linking" and see if it fits your use-case.

Answer (score 0):

You *always* need to ship any libraries your application is linked with along with your application. The libraries are just as much a part of your app as the code you wrote yourself. This includes your compilers runtime libraries (which you forgot in this case).

Comment: How to include them?

Comment: @Youssef13 copy them by hand. Put them into your installer/MSI package. Etc. Whatever is most convenient for your application distribution method. As long as the files are included alongside the executable, the method you use to accomplish it matters little.

Comment: @Youssef13 In other words, find them (they should be shipped with your compiler, and will be in the same directory as `g++.exe`) and put them the same directory as your `.exe`.