# CLion output does not work outside the IDE

Tags: c++, clion

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.23)
project(HelloWorld)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(HelloWorld main.cpp)
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It runs perfectly fine in IDE, but calling the generated .exe outside it fails. The terminal does not print anything, as opposed to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61856121/program-works-in-clion-ide-but-exe-doesnt-work). However, `$LASTEXITCODE` returns -1073741701 which translates to  0xC000007B (STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT). Dependency walker fails dramatically when trying to explore the dependencies of the .exe file.

Comment: What compiler do you have CLion sitting on top of?

Comment: This probably means that the runtime dlls for your current compiler are not in a folder listed in the `PATH` environment variable and instead runtime files for a different version of the same compiler are found in the `PATH` and those are incompatible with the compiler you used to build your code.

Comment: See here for how your OS finds dependent dlls: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-unpackaged-apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-search-order#standard-search-order-for-unpackaged-apps)